# Unable to transform utf-16 xml in Mule

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, utf-16, mule4

I am receiving an XML input in utf-16 format (`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>`). While transforming this data in Mule I am getting this error:

```
Declared encoding 'UTF-16' uses 2 bytes per character; but physical encoding appeared to use 1; cannot decode
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,40], while reading `payload` as Xml.
 [row,col]: [1,40]" evaluating expression: "%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload"
```

I am able to perform this transform  the DataWeave playground (https://dataweave.mulesoft.com/learn/#playground) without any issues.

Input payload

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Body>
        <DOC_POST>
            <ACCOUNT>
                <Item>
                    <PLANT>1000</PLANT>
                </Item>
           </ACCOUNT>
  
        </DOC_POST>
    </Body>
</Envelope>
```

Anypoint Studio version: 7.10.0
Mule runtime: 4.3.0

Transformation:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload
```

Comment: Did you try to change the encoding to UTF-8? <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

Comment: @Marko Marinkovic 
 Yes. I tried . I send data as <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  I am not getting this error.  But my use case is to use utf-16  as encoding in input data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to fix this issue by updating the HTTP listener which is receiving the input XML.  I have updated the mime type to text/plain while receiving the data and then use transform to convert it in to XML.  This XML will be of UTF-8 format.

%dw 2.0

### output application/xml

read(payload, "application/xml")

Answer (score 1):

The input XML declares to be encoded in UTF-16 which uses 2 bytes per character but actually uses only 1 byte per character, so the input data is not valid.

Comment: The same input working fine with mule 3 apps. Only seeing this issue with mule 4 application

Comment: Maybe Mule 3 does not validate the encoding in the XML declaration. Clearly Mule 4 is validating it.